# My code is giving cancellationException when I am doing responseFuture.get()

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My code is giving cancellationException when I am doing responseFuture.get()
responseFuture is OperationFuture. I was working on autoML Natural Language, GCP.

```
  // A resource that represents Google Cloud Platform location.
  LocationName projectLocation = LocationName.of(projectId, computeRegion);

  // Set model meta data
  TextClassificationModelMetadata textClassificationModelMetadata =
                                                    TextClassificationModelMetadata.newBuilder().build();

  // Set model name, dataset and metadata.
  Model myModel =
      Model.newBuilder()
          .setDisplayName(modelName)
          .setDatasetId(dataSetId)
          .setTextClassificationModelMetadata(textClassificationModelMetadata)
          .build();

  // Create a model with the model metadata in the region.
  OperationFuture<Model, OperationMetadata> responseFuture = client.createModelAsync(projectLocation, myModel);


  Model response = responseFuture.get()
```

I am getting the below error on the last line

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled. at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.cancellationExceptionWithCause(AbstractFuture.java:1237)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:524)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:487)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:83)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
>   at
>   com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationFutureImpl.get(OperationFutureImpl.java:127)

Answer (score 0):

The `createModelAsync` method won't return the model immediately after calling it, [as stated in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/tutorial#step_3_create_train_the_model):

> The create_model function kicks off a training operation and prints
>   the operation name. Training happens asynchronously and can take a
>   while to complete, so you can use the operation ID to check training
>   status. When training is complete, create_model returns the Model ID.

So the cause of the exception is likely to be that you are trying to get a model which is not trained yet.

Also, I am not sure what you are trying to get with the `responseFuture.get()` method since it does not exist for the [`OperationFuture`](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-java/1.20.0/apidocs/com/google/api/gax/longrunning/OperationFuture.html) you are using. If you want to [get information of the training process](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/language/automl/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/language/samples/ModelApi.java#L88) of the model use `.getInitialFuture()` instead.

Comment: Hey,
When we call responseFuture.get(), it should wait for the training to finish and once the training is completed, it should return the Model. That is what get() method does on a Future. I need the Model, from where I can get the ModelId, which I can use for evaluation and prediction. I am not sure how .getInitialFuture() will give me the modelid. My main purpose is to get the model_id

Comment: Can you try to edit the line below of `create a model with the model...` and add this one: `response = client.create_model(project_location, my_model)`?, the response should return the Model ID along with some other variables.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an extremely ancient question, however I encountered this and did some more digging. The solution is outlined at [configuring-lro-timeouts](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java#configuring-lro-timeouts). Quoting:

> Long running operations (LROs) are often used for API calls that are expected to take a long time to complete (e.g. provisioning a GCE instance or a Dataflow pipeline). The initial API call creates an "operation" on the server and returns an operation ID to track its progress.
>
> Our generated gRPC clients provide a nice interface for starting the operation and then waiting for the operation to complete. This is accomplished by returning an OperationFuture. When you call get() on the OperationFuture we poll the operation endpoint to check on the operation. These polling operations have a default timeout that varies from service to service and will throw a java.util.concurrent.CancellationException with the message: Task was cancelled. after that timeout has been reached.

e.g.

```
ClusterControllerSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = ClusterControllerSettings.newBuilder();
TimedRetryAlgorithm timedRetryAlgorithm = OperationTimedPollAlgorithm.create(
        RetrySettings.newBuilder()
                .setInitialRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(500L))
                .setRetryDelayMultiplier(1.5)
                .setMaxRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(5000L))
                .setInitialRpcTimeout(Duration.ZERO) // ignored
                .setRpcTimeoutMultiplier(1.0) // ignored
                .setMaxRpcTimeout(Duration.ZERO) // ignored
                .setTotalTimeout(Duration.ofHours(24L)) // set polling timeout to 24 hours
                .build());
settingsBuilder.createClusterOperationSettings()
        .setPollingAlgorithm(timedRetryAlgorithm);
ClusterControllerClient clusterControllerClient = ClusterControllerClient.create(settingsBuilder.build());
```